# 'HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: apache, hadoop

Im new to Hadoop.
I tried to install Hadoop on windows, I followed the documentations.
However I encounter a problem, and I cant run it properly.
**important to mention, I used the java & Hadoop environment variables and changed the path as well.

That's the ending of my error.

YARN_DIR=share\hadoop\yarn
YARN_LIB_JARS_DIR=share\hadoop\yarn\lib
'HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'The' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: For which command do you get error ?

Comment: hadoop-env.cmd
Im doing it in, ..etc\hadoop>hadoop-env.cmd
btw im using hadoop 2.8.1